# Impossible to get data from controller in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, web, get, routes

I want to send my data from controller to xedit.blade.php, but I get the same error

in controller:

```
public function index5()
    {
        $users=User::all();

    return view('xedit')->with('users',$users);//xedit is from xedit.blade.php

    }
```

my route:

```
Route::get('admin/edit', function () {
    return view('xedit');
})->name('edit');

Route::get('edit', 'Admin\UserController@index5');
```

I get the error:

```
Undefined variable: users
```

Comment: Where you get the error `Undefined variable: users`?

Comment: inside xedit.blade.php

Comment: Try removing this route `Route::get('admin/edit', function () {
    return view('xedit');
})->name('edit');`

Comment: but I must have a named route for edit. for example in app.blade.php ,I need the name for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove this route

```
Route::get('admin/edit', function () {
    return view('xedit');
})->name('edit');
```

Because when you go to this route there is no users variable. You can pass here also if you want.

If you want named route then you can also named 2nd one like -

```
Route::get('edit', 'Admin\UserController@index5')->name('edit');
```

Also you can send user variable in first one like this-

```
Route::get('admin/edit', function () {
    $users = App\User::all();
        return view('xedit', compact('users'));
    })->name('edit');
```

Comment: but I need to use "edit" in app.blade.php.otherwise, it can't find the route